# Convert second order system into a first order one

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

We have a second order system:

$$\begin{cases} x_1'' = -6x_1 + 4x_2, \\ 
x_2'' = 4x_1 - 6x_2.\end{cases}$$

I have tried converting it the standard way in differential equations, but I do not know how to proceed to converting this system into a first order system.

Answer (score 4):

The usual way is by adding dimensions:
$$\begin{cases}x_1' = x_3, \\x_2' = x_4, \\ x_3' = -6x_1 + 4x_2, \\ 
x_4' = 4x_1 - 6x_2.\end{cases}$$